# Changing facet labels in label_both in ggplot2 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know many questions have been asked about facet labels before but given that the `labeller` API has changed in `ggplot2`, I feel that this question is justified.

I want to be able to change the labels of the facets using the `label_both()` function. The help file states:

```
label_both(labels, multi_line = TRUE, sep = ": ")

labels: Data frame of labels. Usually contains only one element, but facetting over multiple 
        factors entails multiple label variables.
multi_line: Whether to display the labels of multiple factors on separate lines.
sep: String separating variables and values.
```

Using this information, I can define my own labels:

```
label_both(labels = data.frame(AM = c("0", "1", "0", "1"), VS = c("0", "0", "1", "1")), 
           multi_line = F)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "AM, VS: 0, 0" "AM, VS: 1, 0" "AM, VS: 0, 1" "AM, VS: 1, 1"
```

However when I try to use this in the plot, it doesn't work.

```
my_labels <- label_both(labels = data.frame(AM = c("0", "1", "0", "1"), 
                                            VS = c("0", "0", "1", "1")), 
                        multi_line = F)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear, labeller = labeller(.rows = my_labels))
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I realise that I could just redefine that factor labels, but I really want to understand why this won't work.

EDIT: One solution is to define the labels using `as_labeller()`:

```
mylabels = as_labeller(c(`0` = "AM: Zero", `1` = "AM: One"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear, labeller = labeller(am = mylabels, .multi_line = FALSE))
```

But this doesn't use `label_both()`

Comment: How is `p1` defined?

Comment: oops - sorry. added the necessary information.

Comment: I figured out one solution (see edit) but it still doesn't use the function I want to use.

Answer (score 2):

This works and seems to be the canonical use of `label_both`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear, labeller = labeller(.rows = label_both, .multi_line = FALSE))
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't do what I want it to do. I want to be able to change the labels.

Comment: I believe you'll have to write your own labeller then.